# How would you compare two strings so they can be looped and maintain the items per header? Example provided

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare

I'm having an issue printing these two strings (or just one) by keeping them attached and grouped to their headers.  The indication of a new header (h*) is where the new group of pairs begins.

```
headers = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
full = ['h1','a','b','c','h2','d','e','f','h3','g','h','i','j','k']


print('h1' + ':' + 'a')
print('h1' + ':' + 'b')
print('h1' + ':' + 'c')
print('h2' + ':' + 'd')
print('h2' + ':' + 'e')
print('h2' + ':' + 'f')
print('h3' + ':' + 'g')
etc.

output:   
h1:a
h1:b
h1:c
h2:d
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Initialize index to -1.
header_i = -1

# Go through each element.
for elem in full:
    # If element is in the headers list, update header index to element's index in headers.
    if elem in headers:
        header_i = headers.index(elem)
    # Else, print out the current header and element.
    else:
        print(headers[header_i], ':', elem)
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar.  I'm new to Python and obviously need to go back over the basics.  Thank you!